# Wrap text in transparent shape in bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble putting text in a carousel that wraps within a semi-transparent shape. See this image: [slider1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxDzZ.png) for what I'm trying to re-create in Bootstrap. I've got this far (see code), but there are a few problems I'm not sure how to tackle: the text is not wrapping in the transparent shape, and the transparent shape also needs to be created so it is responsive. I'm not sure how to proceed. Please help :)

*UPDATED CODE from Vishal Panara*: This just needs a tweak to the heading in the carousel caption now to put it on the same line.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" >
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>
 <body class="calibre">
<div class="content container">
  <div class="row">
    <section class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="carousel slide hidden-xs" id="summary">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#summary" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#summary" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
     <img src="http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg" alt="Step 1: Test">
      <div class="carousel-content right-caption">
        <h3>Step 1:<h3> <h6><i>Test</i></h6>
        <p><br></p>
        <big><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Orci non varius consectetur, risus enim accumsan massa, vitae mollis purus neque ac odio. Aliquam viverra vestibulum.</p>
            <p><i>Geget facilisis ligula blandit eu!</i></p></big>
     </div>
    </div>
  <div class="item">
     <img src="http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg" alt="Step 2: Test">
  <div class="carousel-content right-caption">
    <h3>Step 2:<h3> <h6><i>Test</i></h6>
        <p><br></p>
        <big><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Orci non varius consectetur, risus enim accumsan massa, vitae mollis purus neque ac odio. Aliquam viverra vestibulum.</p>
        <p><i>Geget facilisis ligula blandit eu!</i></p></big>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
.carousel-content {
 position: absolute;
 top: 10%;
 right: 1%;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)!important;
 color:#fff;
 width: 32%;
 padding: 4rem;
}

h6 {
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  font-size: 35px;
}
```

Comment: can you add your code on jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: can u try adding `word-wrap: break-word;` in the `.carousel-content{..}` ? and also specify your `carousel-content{}`'s width

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for checking this out for me. I'm new to the coding game so you might need to be a bit more specific @Abbr with what you want me to try. I tried adding the code to jsfiddle but had some trouble as it wouldn't let me add header or meta tags to my code. The carousel's content is 1150px x 456px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured I would chime in on this one and give you some tips with the bootstrap carousel.  FIrst of all when it comes to your font being added your font is on the same line but the text is different sizes so it looks different.  Also you have an h3 and immdiately following that you have an h6.  This is very bad practice the h tags are really supposed to go in order from h1, h2, h3, and so on.  So what you can do is put the test text in the h3 and just wrap it in a span then style that span with your specialized font.  Then instead of adding `<big>` and `<i>` tags you can just add a class to your `<p>` tag and style it in your css it will be much easier and correct for html5.

I see that you are wanting to make this responsive so you will want to add a media query to your css giving your `.carousel-content` a different width at smaller screens.

Also you may want to consider making the carousel itself responsive.  I usually add a padding-bottom to the `.carousel .item` and then add a min-height to it.  Then instead of using images use a background for each of your items.  The reason for this is because many images will be a different size and resoluttion and you will have issues of your carousel jumping around when you switch slides.  You don't need to use this suggestion but I figured I would give you the option because it is much better for responsive design.

Here is a fiddle of this in action [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/ku9gb7Lw/)

So your html will look something like the following:

```
<div class="carousel slide" id="summary">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#summary" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#summary" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
     <div class="carousel-content right-caption">
       <h3>Step 1: <span>Test</span></h3>
       <p class="italic">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
       <p>Orci non varius consectetur, risus enim accumsan massa, vitae mollis purus neque ac odio. Aliquam viverra vestibulum.</p>
       <p class="italic">Geget facilisis ligula blandit eu!</p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
     <div class="carousel-content right-caption">
       <h3>Step 1: <span>Test</span></h3>
       <p class="italic">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
       <p>Orci non varius consectetur, risus enim accumsan massa, vitae mollis purus neque ac odio. Aliquam viverra vestibulum.</p>
       <p class="italic">Geget facilisis ligula blandit eu!</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

And Your Css will look like the following:

```
.italic{
  font-style: italic;
}
.carousel-content {
 position: absolute;
 top: 10%;
 right: 1%;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)!important;
 color:#fff;
 width: 32%;
 padding: 4rem;
}
.carousel-content h3 span{
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
  .carousel-content{font-size:12px;width:80%;}
}

#summary .item{
  background-position:center !Important;
  background-size:cover !Important;
  padding-bottom:50%;
  min-height:375px;
}
#summary .item:nth-of-type(1){
  background:url('http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg')
}
#summary .item:nth-of-type(2){
  background:url('http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg')
}
```

Comment: Cheers for the tips! The lack of responsiveness with the carousel size was definitely an issue that I had noticed. This method solves all problems and thanks for the tips on best practice. I used h6 tags as I didn't have any other use for them on this page, but I'll definitely use the css styling technique you pointed out from now on.

Answer (score 0):

```
.my-caption{
    position: absolute;
    top:25%;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #444;
    color:#fff;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 5rem;
}


<div class="item active">
  <img src="http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg" alt="...">
  <div class="my-caption">
  <h3>Step 1: <b>Test</b></h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <p> </p>
  <p>Orci non varius consectetur, risus enim accumsan massa, vitae mollis purus neque ac odio. Aliquam viverra vestibulum. </p>
  <p> </p>
  <p><i>Geget facilisis ligula blandit eu!</i></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks heaps Vishal! So close to getting there! Can you help me add the fancy font to "test" in the h3 so it will work in Bootstrap also? I'm having trouble applying the font and getting it to sit on the same line as step 1 (standard font). My preference is to use google font Pacifico if possible https://fonts.google.com/?category=Handwriting&selection.family=Pacifico

Comment: Yes you can add font fr that, I want to see that what was the problem while applying the font. Can you share your code for that?

Comment: No worries Vishal, I updated the code in the question with the tweaks I made to the positioning and transparency that makes it work for me. I over-rode the <h6> tag to make the different font display, but that is a problem because the other part of the heading (Step 1) needs to be a normal font like in my picture. Putting step 1 into <h3> or <p> tag puts it on a different line.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the below code to put both in one line.

---

```
<div class="head">
    <p>Step 1: <span><i>Test</i> </span></p>
    </div>
```

---

```
.head>p>span{font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive; font-size: 35px;} .head>p{ font-size: 24px;}
```